# How to extract text between two delimeters in python?

Tags: python

First of all am python newbie and I searched for similar question but xould not gt quite what I want. So I beg pardon :-)

So, my issue is:

There is a log file with several "show running" outputs combined with some other irrelevant details between them.
I want to extract only the show running detals between the "show run" and "end" delimeters

I have managed to get such a block but unfortunatey I can only get the first such block (working)
BUT this is NOT what I want.
What I want is to extract the last block between  my delimeters "show run" and "end" (failing).

My working script (working) goes as follows

- Open the log file and read line by line
- When "show run" is ecountered, break
- Search for a matching pattern of the last closing delimeter "end"
- As long as "end" is NOT ecountered print that line.
  This way the script will print the lines just after "show run" until the line before "end" is found, principally printing the show run output block.
- Then the script exits.

(The faiing part)
I thought of including a counter to count the number of times "show run" is found.
Lets say the counter = 3. So the printing of what I want should start at the 3rd "show run".

So far I have failed to combine the counter and the starting of the printing.
How to tell python to remember the counter and start what is supposed to do from there?

My script

```
import re

# Script to extract show running output from a raw/unformatted(not easily readable) log file
file = input("Please enter the path to the config file: ")


def myCounter():
    counter = 0
    with open(file, "r") as f0:
        for line in f0:
            if line.strip() == "show run": # count number of times the delimeter "sh run" appears in the file
                counter+=1
    return(counter) # return those number of times, which is at the same time supposedly the starting position of printing

def extract():
    position = myCounter() # tried to mark the starting point
    with open(file, "r") as f1:
        for line in f1:
            if line.strip() == "show run": # I commented "and position" from "myCounter()" out because it did not work. 
                                           # I wanted the script to remember the last position of "sh run" and start from there
                break

        for line in f1:
            pattern2 = r"\s{3}end"
            match2 = re.findall(pattern2, line)
            if match2: 
                break
            print(line.lstrip(), end="")
        print("end\n")

if __name__=="__main__":
    extract()
```

Sample log file(identation is intentional):

```
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
show run
            Building configuration...#1
            
            Current configuration : 5154 bytes
            !
            ! Last configuration change at 10:48:50 UTC Mon Dec 16 2019
            ! a lot of other configuration data
            !
            end
            
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
show run
            Building configuration...#2
            
            Current configuration : 5154 bytes
            !
            ! Last configuration change at 10:48:50 UTC Mon Dec 16 2019
            ! a lot of other configuration data
            !
            end
            
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
show run
            Building configuration...#3
            
            Current configuration : 5154 bytes
            !
            ! Last configuration change at 10:48:50 UTC Mon Dec 16 2019
            ! a lot of other configuration data
            !
            end
            
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
show run                             <---------------------------I want to skip all other 1-3 "show run"...."end" blocks and extract this last one!
            Building configuration...#4
            
            Current configuration : 5154 bytes
            !
            ! Last configuration change at 10:48:50 UTC Mon Dec 16 2019
            ! a lot of other configuration data
            !
            end
            
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
a lot irrelevant data
```

Answer (score 1):

That should do it:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
    start = s.rfind("show run") + len("show run")
    end = s.rfind("end")
    substring = s[start:end]
    print(substring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether usage of regex is reasonable here. My approach would be the following, considering, that your sample log is stored as text in variable `log`:

```py
# Define boundaries where important log lines start/end
start = "show run"
end = "end"
# Which result you want to print
begin = 3

# Store all findings
findings = []
# Indicate whether to store lines or not
append = False
# List to keep each individual finding
finding = []

# Iterate over each line
for line in log.splitlines():
    # Set append to True if important lines start and skip processing this line
    if line.startswith(start):
        append = True
        continue
    # Set append to True, store the current finding as a strin and skip processing of this line
    elif line.endswith(end):
        append = False
        findings.append('\n'.join(finding))
        finding = []
        continue
    
    # Append current line to your current finding if append is set
    if append:
        finding.append(line)

# Print finding at index `begin` (3)
for count, finding in enumerate(findings):
    if count == begin:
        print(finding)
        print("-------")
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a generator that yields all the text blocks in a file, and another that iterates through the results of this generator until it can't get any more, returning the last value:

```
def text_blocks(file, start, end):
    "Yield text blocks in `file` delimited by `start` and `end`"
    r = []
    in_block = False
    for line in file:
        if line.strip() == start:
            in_block = True
        elif in_block:
            if line.strip() == end:
                yield r
                r = []
            r.append(line)

def last(it):
    "Return the last item in an iterator"
    for item in it:
        pass
    return item

with open(file) as f:
    print(last(text_blocks(f, "show run", "end")))
```

Or if you specifically want to get the nth text block, you could write a parsing function that also counts the blocks like this:

```
def nth_text_block(file, start, end, n):
    r = []
    in_block = False
    count = 0
    for line in file:
        if line.strip() == start:
            in_block = True
        elif in_block and count == n:
            if line.strip() == end:
                return r
            else:
                r.append(line)
        elif in_block and line.strip() == end:
            count += 1
            in_block = False
    raise EOFError

with open(file) as f:
    print(nth_text_block(f, "show run", "end", 3))
```